# what is the use onClose() in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, user-interface, java-me

```
public boolean onClose() {
    if (isRequireSettle()) {
        Dialog.alert("close??");
    } else {
        close();
        return true;
    }
}
```

What happens on the screen if the `onClose()` method is called?

Comment: -1 just because you could have answered your own question by putting a minimum effort into reading some documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Indicates a close event has occurred.

The default implementation is activated by specifying `Screen.DEFAULT_CLOSE`. It will call `Screen.onSavePrompt()` if the screen is dirty, then call `Screen.close()` if successful.

> Returns: True if the screen closes; otherwise, false.
>   Since: BlackBerry API 3.6.0

Ref: [net.rim.device.api.ui - Class Screen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html)